# Nesting pre inside code in Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

I am a beginner to Shiny and following the [tutorial](http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/). I have a codeblock, inside `mainPanel` as follows:

```
code(
     "# given path to a .txt file the function readCorpus loads
      # all sentences into a character vector and returns it
      readCorpus <- function(pathToFile){
        con <- file(pathToFile) 
        # readLine throws a warning if the last line of the text file is not terminated 
        # by caridge return
        sentences <- readLines(con)
        close(con)
        return(sentences)
       }
")
```

but in the output all line breaks are ignored as shown in the image[image]

I have already tried nesting the `pre` inside `code` but the output is still not properly formatted as shown in this image

[image: pre() nested inside code()]

**Question:** How can i render a block of code, that is properly formatted?